# How to find and remove different classes with a regex

Tags: regex

I want to remove all `data-reactid` properties from a document. However, all the IDs inside are different. How can I find them all at once, and replace them with empty string? (to remove them).

From:

```
data-reactid=".25lvfez8hmo.4.0.0.1.0.1.0"
data-reactid=".25lvfez9hmo.4.0.0.1.0.1.0"
data-reactid=".25lvfez10hmo.4.0.0.1.0.1.0"
```

To:

```
Nothing
```

etc.

Comment: I am not sure this can be done using only regex as regex is primarily used to find matches, not execute functionality. Once you find the data-reactid="..." string in the document you can just replace the whole string with an empty value

Comment: can you specify the technology?

Comment: I have but someone removed my tag. Notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match `data-reactid="` and then match not a double quote using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^"]+` followed by a `"`

[`\bdata-reactid="[^"]+"`](https://regex101.com/r/I7jS1s/1)

Replace with an empty string.

Comment: Simple and to the point. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
`cat your_file | sed 's/^data-reactid=.*//'`

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not entirely sure which language you are opting to use to parse the document data to remove the values as you are suggesting, but if you are good using Java, this should accomplish what you want.

```
public static void main( String args[] ) {
    String lineOfDocument = "data-reactid=\".25lvfez8hmo.4.0.0.1.0.1.0\"";

    //pattern to find in document line, will find everything in data-reactid=" "
    String pattern = "data-reactid=\".*\"";

    //now fix the line
    String fixedLineOfText= lineOfDocument.replaceAll(pattern, "data-reactid=\" \"");

    //you can now write it back to the document, but for simplicity, I
    //will just print it out
    System.out.println(fixedLineOfText);    //will output data-reactid=" "

}
```

If you want to actually remove the entire line from the document change the replaceAll line with this:

```
String fixedLineOfText= lineOfDocument.replaceAll(pattern, "");
```